# Como mostrar la imagen de usuario en admilte laravel jetstream?

Tags: laravel, adminlte, laravel-jetstream

Hola Comunidad estoy trabajando con laravel jetstream y le acabo de implementar admiLte, en el modelo de usuario hay que hacer el siguiente método para llamar la foto de perfil y mostrarla en una esquina de la plantilla:

```
 public function adminlte_image()
{
        return 'https://picsum.photos/300/300';
    }
```

pero en este método estoy retornado una imagen aleatoria, alguna buena persona que me pueda decir como pudo retornar la imagen de mi usuario que se que esta guardada en la base de datos y se quedan implementadas en una carpeta de laravel que esta public/storage/profile-photos.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado al respecto?

Comment: Ademas de lo que muestres que has intentado, agrega la relacion que existe entre imagenes y usuarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya se soluciono era poner este comando "php artisan storage:link" y luego se pone esto

```
  public function adminlte_image()
{
        return asset('storage/'.$this->profile_photo_path);
   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con lo siguiente:

public function adminlte_image(){

```
    return auth()->user()->profile_photo_url;
}
```

Comment: Convendría que añadas una explicación a tu respuesta, pues solo con el código puede llegar a funcionar, sin embargo, el usuario no logra entender del todo cómo funciona o por qué.